# Android WiFi State Listener

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, android-things

I am new to Android development. How can I set up a listener for WiFi connections/disconnections inside an Activity? It has to be inside of the Activity because I have UART connection set up in it and need to send the WiFi status information to UART Device. I have tried some things with BroadcastReceivers but failed. Here is my last try:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myWifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            if(networkInfo.isConnected()){
                Log.d("WIFI", "CONNECTED");
            }else{
                Log.d("WIFI", "DISCONNECTED");
            }
        }
}};
```

I may also need some help on how to register the BroadcastReceiver, currently I'm doing this inside of the Activity's `onResume`:

```
this.registerReceiver(this.myWifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

And in `onPause`:

```
this.unregisterReceiver(myWifiReceiver);
```

EDIT:

Thanks to [Devunwired](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246461/devunwired)'s answer I've achieved what I wanted, I'm posting the code for future reference.

```
private BroadcastReceiver myWifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SupplicantState newState = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_STATE);

        switch(newState){
            case ASSOCIATED:
                Log.d("WIFI", "CONNECTED");
                break;
            case DISCONNECTED:
                if(!disconnected){
                    Log.d("WIFI", "DISCONNECTED");
                    disconnected = true;
                }
        }
}};
```

I also moved the `BroadcastReceiver` registration to `onStart` (and consequently moved the unregistration to `onStop`), because `onResume` wasn't always called:

```
this.registerReceiver(this.myWifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(
        WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "connections/disconnections" you might not be observing the correct broadcast action. `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` triggers when a default connection is fully established or lost.

You might be more interested in `WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION` or `WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`, which trigger as the association state of the WiFi radio changes.

> I have tried some things with BroadcastReceivers but failed

If the above actions don't satisfy your needs, I would encourage you to elaborate on the failures you are experiencing.